# Sections of a certain tautological bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let us think $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |z|=1\}$ and, more in general, $S^{2k+1}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^{k+1}:\ |z|=1\}$. We consider two actions of $S^1\times S^1$:

(1) On $\mathbb{C} P^1$ via $(\theta,\zeta)[a:b]=[\theta a:\zeta b]$

(2) On $S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1}$ via $(\theta,\zeta)(s_1,s_2)=(\bar{\theta}s_1,\bar{\zeta}s_2)$

Then we can consider the fibred product $\mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})$, which is a fibre bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^k\times\mathbb{C}P^k$ with fibres diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Let $\pi_1,\pi_2:\mathbb{C}P^k\times\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^k$ be the projections and let $\mathcal{O}_1(-1)=\pi_1^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}P^k}(-1)$, $\mathcal{O}_2(-1)=\pi_2^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}P^k}(-1)$ be the pull-backs of the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^k$. Then there is an identification
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_1(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_2(-1)) &\longrightarrow & \mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})\\
[as_1,bs_2]&\longmapsto&[[a:b],(s_1,s_2)]
\end{array}
$$
where $[as_1,bs_2]$ is a generic element of the fibre over $([s_1],[s_2])\in\mathbb{C}P^k\times\mathbb{C}P^k$, which is $\mathbb{P}(\langle s_1\rangle\oplus\langle s_2\rangle)$.

Finally consider the tautological bundle
$$
\rho:\mathcal{O}(-1)\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_1(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_2(-1))
$$
and let $u\in H^2(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_1(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_2(-1)))\simeq H^2(\mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1}))$ be its Euler class. If $\sigma$ is a smooth section of $\rho$ transverse to the zero-section, then $PD(u)$ is represented by the submanifold $\sigma^{-1}(0)$.

> **Question:** what is an example of such $\sigma$?

I am aware that finding $\sigma$ tantamounts to finding a complex number $c(a,b,s_1,s_2)$ depending on $a,b,s_1,s_2$ such that
$$
c(\lambda\theta a,\lambda\zeta b,\bar{\theta}s_1,\bar{\zeta}s_2)=\frac{1}{\lambda}c(a,b,s_1,s_2)
$$
for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $(\theta,\zeta)\in S^1\times S^1$, but I am not able to find it. Any hints?

N.B.: I am reasonably happy if $\sigma$ is not smooth but just meromorphic since then I can find $PD(u)$ in terms of the zeroes and poles of $\sigma$ anyway.

**Addendum:**

So it seems that a possible (meromorphic) choice is
$$
\sigma([as_1,bs_2])=\left(\frac{as_1}{bs_2^0},\frac{s_2}{s_2^0}\right),
$$
where $s_2=(s_2^0,\ldots,s_2^k)$ as an element of $\mathbb{C}^{k+1}$.

If I am not wrong (am I?) it looks like $\sigma$ has no zeroes and that it has poles when either $b=0$ or when $a\neq0,s_2^0=0$. What about the case $a=0,s_2^0=0$?

> **Question:** Can any one confirm I am describing the zeroes and the poles of $\sigma$ correctly?
>
> **Question:** Is there the possibility of finding a smooth section rather than meromorphic?

**Follow-up:**

Thanks to Jez answers now we know that $\sigma$ is a right choice. In case anyone is interested I will keep explaining my problem and tell the next point where I am stuck:

Using the identification
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_1(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_2(-1))\simeq \mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})
$$
above it turns out that the pole locus of $\sigma$ is the union of
$$
P:=\{[1:0]\}\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})
$$
and
$$
Q:=\mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times (S^{2k+1}\cap H^0))
$$
where $H^0=\{(z^0,\ldots,z^k)\in\mathbb{C}^{k+1}:\ z^0=0\}$. Then
$$
PD(u)=-[P]-[Q].
$$
For brevity let us define $\alpha:=PD^{-1}[P]$ and $\beta:=PD^{-1}[Q]$. Hence $u=-\alpha-\beta$.

Given the map
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
\iota: & \mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})& \longrightarrow & (\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1)\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})\\
 & \left[x,(s_1,s_2)\right] & \longmapsto & [(x,x),(s_1,s_2)]
\end{array}
$$
I would like to compute $\iota^!(u)=-\iota^!(\alpha)-\iota^!(\beta)$. Note that
$$
\iota^!(\alpha)=(PD^{-1}\circ\iota_\ast\circ PD)(\alpha)=(PD^{-1}\circ\iota_\ast)[P]=PD^{-1}[\iota(P)].
$$
Similarly $\iota^!(\beta)=PD^{-1}[\iota(Q)]$.

I know how to prove (I can provide the details if needed) that $\iota^!(\alpha)=\rho_1^*\alpha\smile\rho_2^*\alpha$ where
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
\rho_j: & (\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1)\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})& \longrightarrow & \mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})\\
 & \left[(x_1,x_2),(s_1,s_2)\right] & \longmapsto & [x_j,(s_1,s_2)]
\end{array}
$$

> **Question:** What is $\iota^!(\beta)$?

It is quite straightforward to prove that $\beta=-\pi^*c_1(\mathcal{O}_2(-1))$, where
$$
\pi:\mathbb{C}P^1\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times S^{2k+1})\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}P^k\times\mathbb{C}P^k
$$
is the projection and also that
$$
\iota(Q)=\Delta_{\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1}\times_{S^1\times S^1}(S^{2k+1}\times (S^{2k+1}\cap H^0))
$$
but I do not know more than that yet.

Comment: What  is a tautological bundle?

Comment: @RobArthan I assume the OP means a trivial bundle.

Comment: Rob and Ben, the tautological bundle is a fairly well-known concept (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle). It is not trivial at all. If it were, its Euler class would vanish and all the fuss I made above wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So it's what used to be called the universal bundle once upon a time. I wonder where the strange change of name came from.

Comment: @RobArthan, there are a couple of universal bundles, so this language (which has been around longer than I've been doing mathematics) is a bit more precise. Perhaps it's more prevalent in complex geometry and algebraic geometry than in topology.

Comment: I like the word tautological for this. $\mathscr{O}(1)$ seems pretty universal to me as well, but tautological to me signifies that I should use the definition: the points have to correspond to the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your section $\sigma$ is correct, except that the denominator in the first term should be $b s^0_1$ instead of $b s^0_2$.  This has poles on $\{b=0\} \cup \{s^0_1=0\} \cup \{s^0_2=0\}$.  If it were finite at $a=s^0_1=0$ then by continuity it would have to be finite at $a=\varepsilon, s^0_1=0$ for small $\varepsilon$, which it isn't, so $a=s^0_1=0$ is a pole.

To answer your other questions it really comes down to the distinction between smooth and holomorphic.  There is a smooth section transverse to the zero section: simply use a partition of unity to perturb the zero section.

There is, however, no holomorphic global section except $0$.  To see this, note that we have a tower of bundles: $E \rightarrow P \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^k\times \mathbb{CP}^k$, where $P$ is the projective bundle and $E$ is the tatuological bundle over $P$, and suppose $\sigma$ is a holomorphic global section of $E$ over $P$.  For each $(s_1, s_2) \in \mathbb{CP}^k \times \mathbb{CP}^k$ consider restricting $\sigma$ to the fibre of $P$ over $(s_1, s_2)$.  This gives a holomorphic section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$, which must therefore be $0$.  Hence $\sigma$ vanishes on all of $P$.

**Added in response to comment:**

The statement above about the denominator is incorrect; the version given in the question is right (and a corresponding comment applies to the pole locus).  Explicitly, on $\{b, s^i_2 \neq 0\}$ we can choose our trivialisation $\phi_i$ of $E$ so that that the $i$-component in the second factor is $1$.  Then the transition map $\psi_{ij}$ is given by $s^j_2/s^i_2$.

I had been uneasy about the apparent asymmetry in the pole locus $\{b=0\} \cup \{s^0_2=0\}$ suggested in the question, given that the whole setup is invariant under transposing the factors, but of course if you make this transposition then not only do $s^0_1$ and $s^0_2$ get swapped, but $a$ and $b$ too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jez, and for the explanation on smooth and holomorphic sections. On the other hand I am quite sure that I took the right denominator: if we take the one you propose the section depends on choices of representatives of $[s_1]$.

Comment: You're right; sorry about that!  I've added a note to my answer.